# CSS for input[type="submit"]

Tags: html, css, input, css-selectors

Before I start crying, could someone please explain why none of the attempted CSS soltions for styling a submit button have any effect at all? I've gone for `font-size: 50px` to make it obvious if I hit the right element, which I haven't yet:

```css
 input[type="submit"].wysija-submit  {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 50px!important;
    }
    
    .wysija-submit input[type="submit"] {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 50px!important;
    }
    
    .wysija-submit.wysija-submit-field input[type="submit"] {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 50px!important;
    }
```

```html
   <input class="wysija-submit wysija-submit-field" type="submit" value="Sign-up">
```

Comment: The first one works. The other two are meaningless (The space means that you are targeting the button **inside** the class, instead your class is applied to button). What's your browser?

Comment: See [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t9bkdkk/) that the first one works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one **does** work.

```css
input[type="submit"].wysija-submit  {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 50px!important;
}
```

```html
<input class="wysija-submit wysija-submit-field" type="submit" value="Sign-up">
```

---

`.wysija-submit input[type="submit"]` and `.wysija-submit.wysija-submit-field input[type="submit"]` contain [descendant combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) so they won't match because the left hand side matches the input, then the right hand side matches nothing because inputs can't have descendants.

Comment: As a side note, the reason this didn't seem to work was caching on Chrome. I did a hard page reload and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

The space character in CSS is the [Descendant Combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators). It tells your CSS compiler to select any descendant of the previous selector.

What your current selector is doing is trying to select any element with a `class` attribute containing `.wysija-submit.wysija-submit-field`, then it's trying to find an `input` element whose `type` is *submit* **inside** that element. This would work for the following markup:

```
<elem class="wysija-submit wysija-submit-field">
  <input type="submit" />
</elem>
```

To get this to select the `input` element whose `type` is *submit* **and** whose `class` contains *wysija-submit* and *wysija-submit-field*, you'll need to change your selector from:

```css
.wysija-submit.wysija-submit-field input[type="submit"] { ... }
```

To:

```css
input[type="submit"].wysija-submit.wysija-submit-field { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: @Robin I've updated my answer. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: @Robin on a side-note I wrote a small web application a while back which attempts to reveal what a CSS selector is doing. This can be found at https://selectors.io. Pasting your selector in will tell you exactly what the CSS compiler is trying to do with it.

Comment: @BoltClock heh, I thought you might like it. One day I decided I wanted to both learn React and improve my regex knowledge and that was the outcome. It's not perfect. Once I've got a couple more React projects behind me I'm planning on rewriting it as I can only imagine it's a complete mess as it currently stands!

Comment: I would have voted for this answer because it was most helpful, but the one I marked as solution was the simplest. (Although come to think of it my question was asking for "can someone explain..." which you did very clearly. Ho hum.